# Using a dynamic OFFSET & ISBLANK() function

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet I'm working on that we use to run large corporate events. Each segment length has a length as well as corresponding start time. I want each cell in the time column to look above itself and find the previous time and then add it to that segments length.

In column A it has the start time of that segment. Then, in column B, it has the segment length. So for example, `A1: start time` & `B1: segment length`. I then want `B2` or `C2` or `D2` (whichever is next) to go up and look for `A1` and add it to `B1`.

The problem is that there are often blank rows in between so even though they are blank, it returns an error with the offset function statically moving 1 row at a time.

I can provide a screen shot if that helps. But, in short, I'm trying to dynamically find the cell above a given cell with content in it knowing that there could be may blank rows in between and not wanting them to calculate.

Comment: Hi Conway, welcome to Web Applications !! The segment length is then also time based, like `A1 = 12:00:00`, `B1 = 00:35:00` and `E1 = 02:25:00`. The total time would be `Z1 = 15:00:00`? A screenshot often tells more, then words can describe !!

Comment: And even better than a screenshot, is a link to the spreadsheet in question (if you're able to share it).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to achieve the desired effect: get the value in the last non-empty cell in column A above the current row.

```
B2  =OFFSET(A1,-LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN("|",A$1:A1),"\|*$")),0)
```

(And propagate down the B column). This works under the assumption that none of your column A cells end with character `|` (if they are dates, they really shouldn't). Another character could be used instead of `|`.

What the command does:

1. `JOIN("|",A$1:A1)` joins the content of column A, above the current row, separating the values with `|`.
2. `REGEXEXTRACT(...,"\|*$")` extracts only the characters `|` at the end of the string. (This particular character needs to be escaped with a backslash in a regex.) The idea is that these characters correspond to blank cells that we must jump over.
3. `LEN` takes the length of the result, i.e., the number of blank cells at the end.
4. `OFFSET` jumps up by that many rows.